# Is there a way to get the c# plugin for VSC to work on ubuntu linux for a project with target net5.0-windows?

Tags: c#, linux, .net-5

I need to write unit tests for a customers backend.

Given that the customer is heavily invested in a microsoft ecosystem, his backend makes use of some functionalities offered by setting net5.0-windows as target framework.

I meanwhile work on a linux machine (ubuntu 20.10, soon to switch to 21.04), so clearly would prefer keeping my optimized workflow going, instead of having to work on a makeshift VM surrounding.

So just to make sure, before I setup said VM: is there a way to get the WindowsDesktop.App Runtime to work on linux just fine enough to be able to write tests for it? Best using VSC with its C# plugin, but other options would be fine as well.

Comment: `net5.0-windows` is for WPF/WinForms, why do you need for backend side?

Comment: The .NET 5 Desktop Runtime is Windows only, so there's no way to run it natively on Linux, you may be able to run it by using things like Wine but IMO it's not worth trying it as it will probably only waste your time

Comment: Also, why do you need to write tests directly for a WPF/ WinForms application. A good architecture would put all the required logic (i.e Database interfacing, Api calls etc) into a separate C# project, which shouldn't target .net5.0-windows but instead target either just .NET 5 *or* something like .NET Standard 2.0 or 2.1

Comment: I'm wondering myself why this target is used. All I could find out yet was, that there are rather specific requirements for pdf generation. In the end it's something outside of my influence, so I'll probably have to make do with what's there.
I assumed as much about it not being possible/not worth it. But well, was worth a try.

Comment: You don't need WPF or any other desktop application to generate PDF files. It's quite likely that library is using hacks, like Word Interop to have Word save files as PDF. That hack can't be used on servers because a) it requires a Word license for every *end user*, not just the server and b) it's *very* heavy, creating a new Word instance for every request. Careless coding can leave those instances in memory, eventually eating up all RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the answer is as expected: yes, but no (not worth it). Thank you very much to all commenters.